# Found a hidden passage, how to open it?

Tags: farlanders

One tile of "Subsurface Ground" has a hidden passage on it.

[image]

I'd like to use the hidden passage to get deeper into the mines.

How to open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Explosives on the tile that has the hidden passage.